# Ruby On Rails form_for Checkbox Too Small

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, form-for

I am having trouble with formatting a `checkbox` in my form.

It currently appears really small in my form and i have no idea how to make it larger.

the code looks like:

```
<%= f.label :email %>   <%= f.email_field :email %>

<%= f.label :password %>   <%= f.password_field :password %>

<%= f.label :remember_me %>     <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
```

Maybe its an issue I can resolve with CSS but currently my other fields are not using any..

Just some more info, I'm using twitter bootstrap, so any solution with it will work great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add CSS class and style option.

```
<%= f.check_box :remember_me, :class => "css_class" %>

<%= f.check_box :remember_me, :style => "width: 50px; height: 50px;" %>
```

May be this will help you.

Comment: It makes the area around the tiny checkbox larger

Answer (score 3):

You can resolve it with CSS. In your css file add:

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

Adjust the size according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, just use css to change the default size of checkbox -

```
Checkbox code:

<%= f.check_box :remember_me, :class => "css_class" %>

CSS code:

<style type="text/css">
input.css_class
{
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}
</style>
```